# Counting specified repeated characters in python

Tags: python

A programmer is building a function that checks if the letter ’a’ in one string occurs the same number of times as ’z’ in a second string.

```
def check_words(word1, word2):
    count1 = 0
    for char in word1:
        if char == "a":
            count1 += 1
            
    count2 = 0
    for char in word2:
        if char == "z"
            count2 += 1
    
    return count1 == count2
```

Is there anyway that this code could be simpler and more modular by placing existing code into a new function.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because working code seeking alternatives.

Comment: If your solution does work, take the [CodeReview Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit its [Help Center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to see if your question is on topic over there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .count()  which counts the character you are looking for in a sequence such as a string or a list.

```
s1 = "aaa"
p1 = "a"
s2 = "zzz"
p2 = "z"

def check_words(s1, s2, p1, p2):
    return s1.count(p1) == s2.count(p2)

print(check_words(s1, s2, p1, p2))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas's answer should be the most efficient you can do in Python. Concerning your question about modularizing your code, the best thing to do generally is to try to see which pieces of code do almost the same task, up to some parameter. Here, you can see that:

```py
    count1 = 0
    for char in word1:
        if char == "a":
            count1 += 1
```

and

```py
    count2 = 0
    for char in word2:
        if char == "z"
            count2 += 1
```

are almost identical, the only thing changed being the character. Hence, you can write this as a function and call it in your code:

```py
def count(word, c):
    count = 0

    for char in word:
         if char == c:
             count += 1
    
    return count

def check_words(word1, word2):
    count1 = count(word1, "a")
    count2 = count(word2, "z")
    
    return count1 == count2
```

You can see that this code is very similar to @Andreas'. The difference is that they're using the `count` method of a string object which is already implemented in Python, and should be much faster than this pure-Python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def check_words(word1, word2):
    dict_1 = Counter(word1)
    dict_2 = Counter(word2)
    return dict_1['a'] == dict_2['z']
```

This should be fastest way to do so, of course it's better to add 2 more arguments instead of hardcoding 'a' and 'z'